# Язык у колокола

Tags: этимология

Почему било у колокола называется язык?

Answer (score 3):

По ассоциации с языком-органом речи. Праславянский корень древнего славянского слова ЯЗЫКЪ происходит от и.-е.корня *eng- узок.Возможно, слово ЯЗЫК некогда означало узкую полоску ткани, кожи. Значение "орган в полости рта"у него вторично. Человек говорит с помощью органа, похожего на узкую полоску кожи и мышц, колокол тоже "говорит"с помощью узкой ленты  металла, потому это и язык.

О колоколах и билах интересно почитать здесь:http://campanologia.ru/archives/60

Comment: Связь *языка* с понятием *узкий* притянута за уши.  
>ЯЗЫК 
род. п. -а, мн. языки, нередко с семинаристским ударением язЫки, диал. лязык "язык", новгор., белозерск. (где л- – от лизать), язычок, укр. язик, блр. язык, др.-русск. азыкъ, ст.-слав. зыкъ (Остром., Клоц., Супр.), болг. език, сербохорв. jезик, род. п. мн. jезика, диал. jазик, словен. jezik ... Праслав. *jezykъ – расширение на -kо- типа kamykъ : kamy от *jezy-, которое родственно др.-прусск. insuwis "язык", лит. liezuvis (где l- от liezti "лизать"), др.-лат. dingua, лат. linguа (под влиянием lingo "лижу")  
(из Фасмера)

Comment: Это не за уши притянуто, это мнение учёных института им.Потебни, этимологич. словарь Цыганенко: Др.-рус.
слово языкъ появилось из праслав. *jezykb - тожд. в связи с изменением
у вост. славян носового гласн. en (in). Слав. слову язык
родственны др.-инд. jihva "язык" и лат. lingua "язык" (см. лингвистика).
Полагают, что праслав. *jezyk происходит от и.-е. корня *eng- "узок" -
того же, что в слове *azbkb " узок (чередов. е//9). Возможно, слово
язык некогда обозначало узкую полосу кожи, ткани и т. п.

Comment: Это подтверждается тем, что в совр.русск.существует значение" ЯЗЫК-
5.      Что-либо, имеющее удлиненную форму (язык колокола, пламени и т.п.)" (перен.). Переносное значение - по внешнему виду, а когда-то в и.-е. оно было одним из главных. И Фасмер это не отрицает, признавая родство с языками, сохранившими носовой гласный.

Comment: Об этом говорит и Даль: Прочие значения языка выведены или из наружного вида его, или как от орудия речи. Мысок языком, клином. || Язык колокола, било, клепало, железный пест || Арх. подводная ледяная коса ||  язычок органа, пружинка, крючок, по коему бьют играя.Язык мялицы || Язык кларнета, гобоя, пищик, тонкая деревянная пластинка || Язык в ловушке, продольная палочка с зарубкою || задвижка, которая входит в проушину дужки висячего замка. Ключ бородкой замыкает язычок. Язычком зовут и спуск, собачку у ружейного замка и все сему подобное.

Comment: Этимология *языка*, какой бы она ни была, не имеет отношения к колокольному языку, здесь нет сомнений. Вы привели слова Даля : *орудие речи*. Мои слова : *болтается и извлекает звуки*.  
Обувной язычок просто похож на язык.

Comment: Полная каша)))
Людмила привела правильную этимологию, возводящую "язык" к и.-е. корню с общим *значением* "узкий". А что касается происхождения от этого же корня *современного* русского слова "узкий", то это отбельная песня.
В принципе возможно и то и другое, не берусь сейчас разбираться, но это две *разные* проблемы. Ваш спор совершенно это не учитывает.
У Софии все разложено по полочкам. Ну в первом приближении хотя бы.

Answer (score 2):

«Язык»  -  очень сложное в этимологическом отношении слово. Предполагается, что существовал и.-е. корень со значением язык-орган, но его дальнейшее развитие  в общеевропейских языках довольно противоречиво, и сравнительная грамматика с трудом находит соответствия и объясняет  различия  для каждого конкретного случая.

В др.-рус. языке слово «языкъ» отмечается с 10 века, но  при этом можно предположить, что значение «орган речи» не было старшим. Предполагается, что общеславянский вариант jezukъ, где   kъ –суффикс,  соотносится  со словами, имеющими отношение к глаголу «вязать» – узы,  узел, узкий  (связанный), при этом возможны два исходных  варианта: узы или узкий.

Если это «узкий», то старшим значением является орган речи, а если  это «узы», то  исходным значением  будет речь – то, что связывает, объединяет людей в  народ, в племя, а потом и просто «народ, племя».

Что касается  языка у колокола, то здесь, безусловно, перенос по сходству с языком как  органом  речи.

Answer (score 2):

"Язык" есть и у огня, и у каменной осыпи, да и у многих других вещей, ни как не связанных с речью. При этом - все "языки" похожи внешне. Узкая полоса сложной формы...
Нет, возможно, что изначально "языком" называли именно "подвижную полоску мяса во рту"... Но не только во рту человека. И к речи, равно как и к извлечению звуков, это слово отношения не имело. Так-что колокольный "язык" - всё-таки результат "сходства формы". Так-же как и "снежный язык", тянущийся от какого-нибудь пригорка в поле.
А значение "язык"="набор используемых слов" - пожалуй, одно из самых молодых. До того была "речь" (при чем, изначально - только в значении "чужая речь"), а ещё раньше - "слово".